# WordPress does not allow me to login until another dashboard is open

Tags: wp-login-form

I am trying to login https://whimzy.in/wp-admin but it does not allow me to login until another Admin dashboard is open, anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: What other admin dashboard?  Like a different WP site?  Can you clarify?  This may be a GoDaddy issue stemming from their custom WP Hosting and Management utilities.  You may want to inquire with them.